# how to remove unity 8 system settings?

Tags: uninstall, unity8

How can i remove **unity 8 system settings**?
After installing **unity 8** i don't like it so i searched how to remove and i remove it by running these commands :

```
sudo apt-get remove unity8-desktop-session-mir
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

it removed from my login entry but still **unity 8 system settings** on my ubuntu dash so how can i remove?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First try this command `sudo apt-get remove system-settings`.
2. If working Ok and ignore following steps.
3. If not working appending this message `E: Unable to locate package system-settings`.
4. Search for **system-settings** using this command `whereis system-settings`.
5. On my laptop was **/usr/bin/system-settings**.
6. Remove this file `sudo rm '/usr/bin/system-settings'`.
7. Also remove the **.desktop file** go to **usr/share/applications** drag and drop desktop file into terminal and remove with permission.
8. On my laptop `sudo rm '/usr/share/applications/ubuntu-system-settings.desktop'`.

Comment: See [answer by isalgueiro](http://askubuntu.com/a/857298/18110) for later versions of ubuntu. Package name is ubuntu-system-settings (true on my Ubuntu 16.04 box).

Comment: @cledoux sir did you read my answer !! number 8 is remove ubuntu-system-settings !!!

Comment: Number 8 only removes the desktop entry. I'm referring to the apt package. At least on later Ubuntu versions, step 1 should be `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-system-settings`.

Answer (score 5):

On 16.10:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-system-settings
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

This also removed a bunch of dependencies that `unity8-desktop-session` kept on my system.

Comment: While package name might be scary, it indeed remove unity 8 settings only (and it's dependencies). Even tried to reboot and old systems settings works fine.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 16.04 as well.